# Anaconda3 Python shapely module not found

Tags: python, anaconda, shapely

I am running a Python program in Spyder with Anadaconda 3 that has as its line number 26

```
    from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point, LineString
```

and which is throwing the following errors:

File "C:\Users\Dan\Documents\Students\20Chowdhury\python_code\20-07-01\local_planner.py", line 26, in 
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point, LineString

File "C:\Users\Dan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry_*init*_.py", line 4, in 
from .base import CAP_STYLE, JOIN_STYLE

File "C:\Users\Dan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\base.py", line 18, in 
from shapely.coords import CoordinateSequence

File "C:\Users\Dan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shapely\coords.py", line 8, in 
from shapely.geos import lgeos

File "C:\Users\Dan\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shapely\geos.py", line 145, in 
_lgeos = CDLL(os.path.join(sys.prefix, 'Library', 'bin', 'geos_c.dll'))

File "C:\Users\Dan\anaconda3\lib\ctypes_*init*_.py", line 364, in **init**
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

However, when I run

```
    pip install shapely
```

it says it's already installed.  Also

```
    pip show shapely
```

says I have version 1.7.0

What is going wrong here?  Why is the module not being found by Anaconda?

Comment: When you have Anaconda you install packages with conda (if the packages is available on conda) or pip, at the anaconda prompt. `conda install -c conda-forge shapely`

Comment: Can you do `conda list` and see? Conda and pip might be saving files to different locations and hence package installed using pip is not being found by conda. I think the safer alternative is to use `conda install` for installing packages to be used by Anaconda.